# Get value from table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using JQuery I have a table inside a razor view... I want to get a value(StudentID) according to a click on an img that I have in the same row, I want to get the value and then send it to  an Action Method in the Controller class as a parameter. 
With this sentence I'm just getting an string, for example if a click the img element and in that row the value of `StudentID` is 129, then the value of `id` is

```
"\n 129 \n"
```

I'm expecting `id` to have the value 129.
This is the sentence, what I need to change? I've tried using innertext() but JQuery doesn't recognize it

```
var id = $(this).parent().siblings().eq(3).text()
```

If you want to consult the table this is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td style="display:none" id="tdStudentID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.StudentID)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="~/images/deleteIcon.png" width="20" height="20" class="imgJQuery" />
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: try this selector `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#tdStudentID').text()`

Comment: try this selector `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#tdStudentID').text()` i would also suggest to use class instead of ID as you loop you will create duplicated ID and `ID should always be UNIQUE`. so your selector will be `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdStudentID').text()`

Comment: @guradio you're right about use class attribute and not id, but still I'm getting the same result:  `"\n  129\n  "` I tried using the selector you gave me but it's getting the same result

Comment: can you create a demo or snippet so SO people can actually see the problem in action?

Comment: Much easier if you just use `<img src="..." class="imgJQuery" data-id="@item.StudentID" />` and then `$('.imgJQuery').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); ..... });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's the answer!!!

Comment: @AlexGH, Not really _the answer_. Just a better way. And I cannot duplicate your behavior so its not clear what else you may have been doing wrong. Do you have a `DisplayTemplate` associated with the type that is `StudentID`? Or do you have a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on that property?

Comment: I take that back. I have been able to repeat it (your making an ajax call to a method which has a `string` parameter instead of `int` for that value). Your html would need to be `<td style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.StudentID)</td>` (all on one line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add student id as data attribute on the image instead of putting it inside a hidden td, like

```
<td> <img src="~/images/deleteIcon.png" width="20" height="20" class="imgJQuery" data-student-id='@Model.StudentID'/> </td>
```

Then simply catch it like that

```
$('img').data('student-id')
```

Comment: Yes that's the answer as Stephen Muecke said too, very easy doing it using data- attribute inside img tag, thnxs